# Jenkins missing Build Trigger section after upgrade

Tags: jenkins, build, triggers

I've upgraded Jenkins version (now on 2.127) and plugins and now the UI of job configuration is different and I am missing the build triggers section, especially the `Trigger Builds Remotely` via authentication token. Where is it? Do I need to enable it explicitly? The changelog unfortunately does not mention anything about that and I even can't schedule builds periodically.

[image: Navigation Bar of Job Configuration in Jenkins missing the Build Triggers section]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out: It seems that since the update, the `Multibranch Pipeline` does no longer have this section. So either choose `Pipeline` or set it in the Jenkinsfile via: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/blob/c0828af5b8bd428815e23537c808cd0267017013/Jenkinsfile#L6

The webhook works without a token with the `Generic Webhook Plugin`.

Comment: What is the reason?